# Ping sweeper using sub-processes hitting firewall limits?

Tags: linux, networking, ping, route

I have a ping sweeper:

```
#!/bin/bash

for ip in $(seq 1 254); do  
    ping -c 1 10.11.1.$ip |  grep "bytes from" | cut -d " " -f4 | cut -d ":" -f1 &
done
```

This works and it's displaying a number of results but as it nears the end of my IP range it starts returning the result:

```
ping: recvmsg: No route to host
```

I'm assuming that it's hitting a firewall limit due to the concurrent sub-processes firing ping commands at the same time and would like to limit them. Is there a flag I can use to do this?

Comment: _No route to host_ means exactly that, it has nothing to do with firewall filtering. What does `ip route` output?

Comment: @countermode I pulled  this thread a bit further and you're right. Unfortunately though I don't know which IP is returning the 'No route to host' result due to the multiple threads! Will have to explore further.